# Как узнать тип загрузки системы?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, загрузка, ansible, mbr

После не удачного исполнения плейбука, выполняющего задачу `apt-get dist-upgrade`, сервера с Ubuntu 12.04 перестали загружатся после рестарта.

Пытался с установачного ISO переустановит grub и завершить апгред но резлуьтата не принесло.

Сервера все удаленные с одним жестким диском и доступны по IPMI.

Как узнать тип загрузчика первой стадии - vbr, mbr, gpt, используя установочный ISO?

И какие пути восстановления можно выбрать не переустонавливая всю систему (это работает, но теряется пользовательский контент)?

Comment: почему вы решили, что поврежден именно загрузчик. В любом случае надо начинать с того, что узнать что последнее отображается на экране при загрузке.

Comment: @Mike последнее, что видно - это имя диска и логотип supermicro, потом черный экран. все это удаленно через IPMIView.

Comment: когда вы пытались переустановить grub и закончить апгрейд, что вам удалось, по крайней мере что сказала переустановка ? я просто не знаю как ведет себя grub, если например не может найти ядро или находит, но оно повреждено и не грузится. Доступно ли меню загрузчика при загрузке с ISO. можно ли в нем передать параметры ядру. если да, то стоит попробовать запустить ядро с ISO с передачей ему параметра root=/dev/sda1 (или где у вас на диске корневой раздел), что бы загрузить основную систему, но с использованием ядра и загрузчика с ISO

Comment: @Mike я грузил в востановительном режиме, подгоужал корень и dpkg --configure -a, apt-get dist-upgrade,  aupdate-grub,

Comment: я бы где нибудь развернул бекап и сравнил конфиг груба и ядро, что бы понять, что изменилось. (думаю весь каталог /boot стоит сравнить) вообще конфиг груба стоит посмотреть, что бы знать что он него ожидать. должен ли он показывать свою меню до запуска ядра (стоит включить, что бы понимать где затык) и знать какого вида меню, если grub включает графическое меню, то отобразит ли его IPMI